# R matrix remove rows according to column sum

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix:

```
range<-rep(1:10)
A<-c("9:00","9:00","9:30","10:00","10:00","10:00","10:30","10:30","11:00", "11:30")
B<-c("10:00","11:00","11:00","10:30","11:00","11:30","12:00","11:00","12:00","12:00") 
Fzg<-c("Fzg 1", "Fzg 2", "Fzg 3", "Fzg 4", "Fzg 5", "Fzg 6", "Fzg 7", "Fzg 8", "Fzg 9", "Fzg 10")

mat1<-matrix(0, ncol = 7, nrow = 10)
colnames(mat1) <- c("9:00", "9:30", "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30", "12:00")

rownames(mat1) <- Fzg
for(i in 1:length(range)) mat1[i,which(colnames(mat1) == A[i]):which(colnames(mat1) == B[i])]=1
```

[image]

I want to check every column of the matrix to see if the sum of elements in each column exceeds 3. If the sum exceeds "3", the rows below have to be removed. I have found the single steps to check my matrix. Could You please help me to return this into the loop?

`b<-as.data.frame(mat1[,c(i)] )` - split off the column, which should be checked

`b$sum<-cumsum(b[ ,1])` - define the cumsum of the elements in this column

`x<-b[(b[,2]>3)&(b[,1]!=0),]` - define the rows which have to be removed

`remove<-rownames(x)` - define the row names, which have to be removed

```
`mat1<-mat1[!rownames(mat1) %in% remove,]` - remove the defined rows.
```

In such way has to be checked every column.
As a result, I would like to receive this matrix:

[image]

Thank You in advance!

Comment: I don't understand why rows  and 10 are in the expected output. In column 3 they both have cumsums greater than 3. Isn't this the criterion to be removed?

Answer (score 0):

Second attempt using the cumsum and pivoting, I still don't get why the row 10 should be kept

```r
library(tidyverse)
range<-rep(1:10)
A<-c("9:00","9:00","9:30","10:00","10:00","10:00","10:30","10:30","11:00", "11:30")
B<-c("10:00","11:00","11:00","10:30","11:00","11:30","12:00","11:00","12:00","12:00") 
Fzg<-c("Fzg 1", "Fzg 2", "Fzg 3", "Fzg 4", "Fzg 5", "Fzg 6", "Fzg 7", "Fzg 8", "Fzg 9", "Fzg 10")

mat1<-matrix(0, ncol = 7, nrow = 10)
colnames(mat1) <- c("9:00", "9:30", "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30", "12:00")

rownames(mat1) <- Fzg
for(i in 1:length(range)) mat1[i,which(colnames(mat1) == A[i]):which(colnames(mat1) == B[i])]=1


mat1
#>        9:00 9:30 10:00 10:30 11:00 11:30 12:00
#> Fzg 1     1    1     1     0     0     0     0
#> Fzg 2     1    1     1     1     1     0     0
#> Fzg 3     0    1     1     1     1     0     0
#> Fzg 4     0    0     1     1     0     0     0
#> Fzg 5     0    0     1     1     1     0     0
#> Fzg 6     0    0     1     1     1     1     0
#> Fzg 7     0    0     0     1     1     1     1
#> Fzg 8     0    0     0     1     1     0     0
#> Fzg 9     0    0     0     0     1     1     1
#> Fzg 10    0    0     0     0     0     1     1

mat1 %>%
  data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  pivot_longer(-rowname) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(running_sum = cumsum(value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(value == 0 | running_sum <= 3) %>%
  select(-running_sum) %>% 
  pivot_wider() %>% 
  na.omit()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 8
#>   rowname X9.00 X9.30 X10.00 X10.30 X11.00 X11.30 X12.00
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 Fzg 1       1     1      1      0      0      0      0
#> 2 Fzg 2       1     1      1      1      1      0      0
#> 3 Fzg 3       0     1      1      1      1      0      0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank You for the answer. But the output is not correct. The sum of each column cannot be greater than 3. In Your matrix, the sums of the columns "10:30" and "11:00" are four. For example, the column "10:00" of my initial matrix - the sum of values in this column is six. That's why the rows "Fzg 4", "Fzg 5" and "Fzg 6" should be removed. The next column should be analyzed already without these three rows.